# SQL Double result for left join with grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have Exercise 30:

> Under the assumption that receipts of money (inc) and payouts (out) can be registered any number of times a day for each collection point [i.e. the code column is the primary key], display a table with one corresponding row for each operating date of each collection point.
>   Result set: point, date, total payout per day (out), total money intake per day (inc). 
>   Missing values are considered to be NULL.

this [schema of database](http://www.sql-ex.ru/help/select13.php#db_2) (its Recycling firm)
and here is my code:

```
WITH IO_table
AS
(SELECT point, "date" FROM Income
UNION
SELECT point, "date" FROM Outcome)

SELECT io.point, io.date, SUM(o.out), SUM(i.inc)
FROM IO_table io
LEFT OUTER JOIN Income i ON io.point = i.point AND io."date" = i."date" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Outcome o ON io.point = o.point AND io."date" = o."date"
GROUP BY
io.point, io.date
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZj6J.png) are the results which have doubled sum results. I checked it anywhere but I do not really understand it.

Comment: Can you add the Income and Outcame Data? I guess that Income primary key is also in the outcome table, so when you join the IO_Table you find 2 records for the same key. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is why your sums are multifold: Let's say for the same date and point there are two income records with inc 150 and 250 and three outcome records with out 100, 200 and 300. You join these records, so you get pairs 150-100, 150-200, 150-300, 250-100, 250-200, 250-300. Now you aggregate and sum: That makes inc = 3 x (150+250) = 1200 and out = 2 x (100+200+300) = 1200 instead of the desired inc = 400 and out = 600.

---

When wanting aggregates from different tables, don't join the tables, but the aggregates, e.g.:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  select point, "date", sum(inc) as total
  from Income 
  group by point, "date"
) i ON io.point = i.point AND io."date" = i."date"
```

In your case you want a full outer join of the two aggregates:

```
select 
  point, 
  "date", 
  coalesce(i.total, 0) as inc_total, 
  coalesce(o.total, 0) as out_total
from
(
  select point, "date", sum(inc) as total
  from income 
  group by point, "date"
) i
full outer join
(
  select point, "date", sum(out) as total
  from outcome 
  group by point, "date"
) o using(point, "date");
```

This is standard SQL that works in PostgreSQL. For SQL Server you need `[date]` instead of the standard `"date"` and an `ON clause` instead of the simple `USING` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to distinguish between an Income and an Outcome in your IO_table. So you are adding each value twice, once for an income and once for an outcome. One way to solve this is to add another column in your IO_table to distinguish between the two and then update your join statements to include the new column.

Answer (score -1):

I Guess this is what you are searching for :

```
SELECT X.POINT,X.DATE,SUM(OUT),SUM(INC) FROM (
    SELECT I.POINT,I.DATE,0 AS OUT, SUM(I.INC) AS INC FROM INCOME I
    GROUP BY I.POINT,I.DATE
    UNION 
    SELECT O.POINT,O.DATE,SUM(O.OUT) AS OUT , 0 AS INC FROM OUTCOME O
    GROUP BY O.POINT,O.DATE) AS X
GROUP BY POINT,DATE
```

Comment: Yes, this is it... it works when I change zeroes to null values for this excercise

Comment: if you like my answer please aprove it. If you need to make it work with null values you know you can use SUM(Isnull(inc,0)) for example.